# How to display count in the dashboard page?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Undefined variable error when I tried to display count in the dashboard page

I try to display count for number of tools in my dashboard page. However, it shows error:
**Undefined variable $jumlahalat**

**web.php**:

```
Route::get('/dashboard-admin', function () {
    $jumlahalat = Inventory::count();
    return view('dashboard-admin', compact('jumlahalat'));
});
```

**dashboard-admin.blade.php**:

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-4 gap-4 rounded mt-4 text-md font-bold text-[#fecbcf] w-full">
    <a href="{{ url('/sda/alat') }}" class="text-white" style="text-decoration: none; color: inherit;">
        <div class="bg-[#5479f7] flex gap-3 pl-5 justify-start items-center rounded-lg h-[110px]">
            <div class="h-[70px] w-[70px] rounded-sm bg-white flex justify-center items-center">
                <span class="material-icons text-black" style="font-size: 40px">inventory_2</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="self-center text-start">Jumlah Alat</div>
                <div class="self-center text-start">{{ $jumlahalat }}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

I already defined use `App\Models\Inventory` in web.php

Comment: try dd($jumlahalat) in your route? the tell me what you see

Comment: can you write the full code?

Comment: Route::get('/dashboard-admin', function () {
    $jumlahalat = Inventory::count();
dd($jumlahalat);
    return view('dashboard-admin', compact('jumlahalat'));
});

Comment: still showed "Undefined variable $jumlahalat", should I made any change in the dashboard-admin.blade.php too?

Comment: now in your terminal run `php artisan optimize:clear`
the problem you are facing is because of cache

Comment: still facing the same problem tho T_T

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Did you check what `$jumhalat` in your web.php contains?

Answer (score 0):

This also might be just route/view cache issue.
Try to run these commands on your project

```
php artisan route:clear
```

and also

```
php artisan view:clear
```

Comment: still showed "Undefined variable $jumlahalat"

Comment: Can you try to use
`return view('dashboard-admin', ['jumlahalat' => $jumlahalat]);`
instead of 
`return view('dashboard-admin', compact('jumlahalat'));`?

Comment: still not solving the problems, any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

[image: counter-image]

if you try to do this counter on your dashboard....
then you can try on my way.....
on your controller. you can simply return all of your model....

````
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\ProductCategory;
use App\Models\Products;
use App\Models\Customer;

class PageController extends Controller
{
    public function dashboard()
    {
        $category = ProductCategory::all();
        $products = Products::all();
        $customer = Customer::all();
        return view('admin/dashboard',compact('category','products','customer'));
    }

}```

 and then you can call this on you page for count...

              ```<div class="card-body">
                <div class=" float-end fs-1 fw-bolder opacity-25">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-box"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h5 class="card-title text-center">Total Products</h5>
                    <p class="card-text fs-1 text-center fw-bolder">{{$products->count()}}</p>
                </div>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have imported the correct Inventory model class, normally it would be located in `App\Models\Inventory`

try change the `$jumlahalat = Inventory::count()`

```
Route::get('/dashboard-admin', function () {
    $jumlahalat = Inventory::count();
    return view('dashboard-admin', compact('jumlahalat')); });
```

to `$jumlahalat = Inventory::all()->count();`